# Share link from mobile browser to my app

Tags: android, android-intent, browser, share, intentfilter

I want click share option in mobile browser, then i will chose my app in list of possible app. And finally this link must be received in my app. But haven't this intent filters and i don't now how receive data in app. Please, give me some information for doing this.

Comment: read about broadcasts.

Comment: you have to subscribe with any broadcast and when it will have to check in android which apps can handle the intent your app will get registered if you have done everything correctly in menifiest file.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html

Answer (score 0):

To specify accepted intent actions, an intent filter can declare zero or more action elements, depending on what you want to do with the data, e.g.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    ...
</intent-filter>
```

Once the intent filter is set up for your activity, you can use `getIntent().getData()` to retrieve the Uri object.